# ASP.NET MVC Checkbox resulting HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I was working with `html` checkbox control and bind it with model data but when I run the program I see false passed as `checkbox` value whether it checked or not.

at last searching google I found a code snippet which show how to work with `checkbox` with model data.

My HTML:

```
<input id="IsApproved" type="checkbox" value="true" name="IsApproved">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="IsApproved">
```

what i need to do to create a hidden field for check box with same name but check box value i need to set true and hidden field value i need to set false. it work but really i do not understand how it work?

I just like to know how true and false is passing to action method when checkbox is checked or not.

When checkbox is checked, checkbox data is passing but when not checked then hidden field data is passing....just do not understand the technique. I am new to `MVC` and I search google to understand how this is working but found no results. so please some one tell me how `true/false is passing` when checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: it's just making sure that you're getting a value for IsApproved..  when you check the box it sends two values for IsApproved.. [true, false].. the binder grabs the first value in the list and assigns that to the property.. without the hidden input, nothing would get passed to your action for IsApproved and the value for IsApproved would be null..

Comment: `@Html.CheckBoxFor` is pretty straight forward as long as you're not using a `nullable<bool>`  https://dotnetfiddle.net/MAqhYq

Comment: i am from webform background and there we never use hidden field for each checkbox. what value pass when we do not work with hidden field? why normal check box value will not pass to server side if we do not use hidden field? please elaborate if possible.

Comment: if there is no hidden field and you do not check the checkbox then nothing gets passed to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the thing with check boxes: they only get passed in the HTML request if they are checked. Therefore, I would actually recommend using two radio buttons for what you are trying to do (to be sort of stylistically correct).

You absolutely can use check boxes for this, but that doesn't mean you should and I think you're going to get into trouble doing this more often than not. I prefer to use them for when there is a list of items from which a user can pick 0 or more - so like which mailing lists someone wants to sign up for(zero or more of: none, marketing, sales, etc.). radio buttons are best for when you have two or more mutually exclusive options. Also, with radio buttons, something is always passed with the request. So lets get started:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="IsApproved" value="true">Approved <br />
    <input type="radio" name="IsApproved" value="false">Unapproved
</form>
```

Then, you wanna move to your action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPostAction(bool IsApproved)
{
    /*your logic here */
}
```

so when a user submits the form, the IsApproved will be bound to the bool variable, and you don't have to worry about whether or not the checkbox is selected, or dealing with hidden fields. If the bool is a property in a model, it will automatically bind to that:

```
public class User 
{
    public int UserID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool IsApproved {get;set;}
}
```

and the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPostAction(User user)
{
    /*your logic here */
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so I read the question quickly and didn't realize that you are more interested in how this stuff works, and are not looking for an implementation. When a user submits a request to the MVC framework and there are parameters in the receiving action, the **model binder** takes the raw request and attempts to map it to the object(s) specified in the action method argument. There are default implementations for all types of web controls (checkbox, radio, text box, etc). [Check out this page for more information](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710776/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-An-Absol).

Comment: im not sure that 1 and 0 is the correct values to pass for bool.  the value attributes should be true and false i believe

Comment: I went on a rant about the checkbox because I don't think it's the best choice for the technology you chose. That being said, I realized that you are looking for info on the model binder and gave you a link to check out how it works.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML form checkbox values get sent only when checkbox is checked. In ASP.NET MVC there is a helper method to render checkboxes:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsApproved)
```

If `IsApproved` of type `Boolean` or `bool` (same thing), in the resulting HTML you will see:

```
<input name="IsApproved" type="checkbox" value="true" id="IsApproved">
<input name="IsApproved" type="hidden" value="false">
```

However `IsApproved` can also be a nullable boolean (`bool?`). The resulting HTML will be different:

```
<input name="IsApproved" type="checkbox" value="true" id="IsApproved">
```

In case of nullable boolean you will not see a hidden field. That's because the values is not required in case of nullable property.

---

That said, I recommend you to use HTML helpers instead of writing pure HTML, unless you have some specific application requirements.

Comment: when IsApproved  will be nullable boolean then without hidden field only check box will work?

Comment: few people use `@Html.CheckBoxFor` and few guys use `@Html.EditFor `to render checkbox. do u know which one is best? what special purpose can be achieve by `@Html.EditFor` ? please share knowledge. thanks

Comment: in case of radio button then we need to use hidden field? please answer my 3 questions. thanks

Comment: The hidden field is there to ensure *something* is posted. By default, a checkbox only posts its value when it's checked. Therefore, in the case of a non-nullable bool, an unchecked checkbox would post null, which can't be assigned to bool. However, with a nullable bool, that behavior is exactly what you want, which is why the hidden field is removed.

Comment: Radio's are different because traditionally, one value must be selected, meaning something is always posted. The difference between `CheckBoxFor` and `EditorFor` is that `CheckBoxFor` will always render the same bit of HTML, while `EditorFor` will use an appropriate editor template, if available.

Comment: suppoe i have two radio for sex (male and female) when form post then none is selected then what will happen?

Comment: @Mou nothing will be sent

Comment: In the case of the male/female question, you can deliberately set one to selected and something will (unless the user really monkeys with stuff) always be posted.